# Stacked geom_area produces blank between layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a data like below: (sorry for the big sample, but it's minimal to make the case occurs on the plot)

```
df <- structure(list(predictor = structure(c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), .Label = c("01", "02", "03", "04", 
"05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43"), class = "factor"), category1 = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Competitors Media", 
"Competitors Price", "Distribution", "Natural Demand", "Other", 
"Other Activities", "Own Media", "Own Price"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
    14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 
    14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 
    14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 
    14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 
    14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 
    14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
    14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
    14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 
    14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 
    14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 
    14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 
    14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 
    14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 
    14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
    14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 
    14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 
    14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 
    14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 
    14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 
    14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
    14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
    14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 
    14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 
    14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 
    14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 
    14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 
    14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 
    14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
    14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 
    14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 
    14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 
    14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 
    14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 
    14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
    14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
    14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 
    14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 
    14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 
    14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 
    14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 
    14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 
    14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
    14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 
    14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 
    14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 
    14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 
    14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 
    14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
    14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
    14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 
    14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 
    14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 
    14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 
    14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 
    14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 
    14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
    14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 
    14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 
    14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 
    14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 
    14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 
    14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
    14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
    14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 
    14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14837, 14844, 14851, 
    14858, 14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 
    14921, 14928), class = "Date"), value = c(131970.980379196, 
    131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 
    131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 
    131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 131970.980379196, 
    131970.980379196, 245.776975596695, 2592.81123218455, 2394.41788371713, 
    794.168946135254, 777.493482699343, 1491.18842894969, 227.165967297687, 
    -405.943313017955, -780.434022010586, 347.653635025463, 1302.51002681435, 
    1418.82882868315, 391.352282511533, 139.954782408537, 557.386280511255, 
    860.910966958813, 1258.2157060297, 2149.37830286701, 2691.89086535467, 
    3293.89829993671, 4088.50777807848, 4473.20767136667, 4551.86190905075, 
    3741.37032522276, 4127.33070308922, 4066.07115258527, 3701.28691563376, 
    4325.47887879336, -72926.7301943435, -67916.3854465138, -61120.2053393434, 
    -54147.8698229716, -49236.4024008508, -47470.8073910042, 
    -41359.7595381763, -33591.8781577481, -26172.7923548125, 
    -21847.8659440037, -20266.7835336002, -24151.7541214564, 
    -26878.4009768588, -26384.0179243477, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5064.04904072815, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -255.92797274953, 
    -477.999244209079, -988.82164999467, -587.738357700427, -569.535553280643, 
    -593.682130572193, -792.934610635432, -361.628557396076, 
    -255.107761517844, -302.558636405627, -461.550882648102, 
    -278.67688067767, -193.198364873309, -306.225679445943, 1.35968370536031e-33, 
    4.52442411489047e-34, 1.51049784252333e-34, 5.04284771138834e-35, 
    1.68016374683172e-35, 5.60840072574964e-36, 1.86632494739232e-36, 
    6.2210831579744e-37, 2.07369438599147e-37, 6.90445971699431e-38, 
    2.30462853352233e-38, 7.68209511174111e-39, 2.56855327355761e-39, 
    8.53042463328307e-40, 7.7469498657489e-32, 2.59145756571069e-32, 
    8.63819188570231e-33, 2.8793972952341e-33, 9.59799098411368e-34, 
    3.1947598561407e-34, 1.0626347160983e-34, 3.55125666412206e-35, 
    1.18603745732262e-35, 3.9488877191782e-36, 1.31629590639273e-36, 
    4.38765302130911e-37, 1.46026577115444e-37, 4.87440827836059e-38, 
    1.84217877694519e-34, 6.12949177139086e-35, 2.04871599967684e-35, 
    6.82905333225613e-36, 2.27524069557607e-36, 7.59523980367998e-37, 
    2.52841535569873e-37, 8.42805118566244e-38, 2.80823998004484e-38, 
    9.36079993348279e-39, 3.12137705967024e-39, 1.0393486047141e-39, 
    3.46449534904701e-40, 1.15594219819165e-40, 4.2168087269196e-18, 
    1.4056029089732e-18, 4.69872972428184e-19, 1.56222723311593e-19, 
    5.2208108047576e-20, 1.73491559050407e-20, 5.78305196834689e-21, 
    1.92768398944896e-21, 6.42561329816321e-22, 2.14053242995062e-22, 
    7.14849479420657e-23, 2.37747692032039e-23, 7.91153637336345e-24, 
    2.64253346886962e-24, 2.6723934953876e-16, 8.90797831795868e-17, 
    2.97046815448853e-17, 9.90156051496176e-18, 3.29937812315162e-18, 
    1.09979270771721e-18, 3.66597569239069e-19, 1.22313394596586e-19, 
    4.07711315321955e-20, 1.35675362073524e-20, 4.52251206911748e-21, 
    1.50750402303916e-21, 5.03643389515356e-22, 1.67538515287761e-22, 
    3.27912196737765e-14, 1.09609811217239e-14, 3.64601673295837e-15, 
    1.217632003271e-15, 4.05877334423667e-16, 1.35292444807889e-16, 
    4.51739180121257e-17, 1.50197544659606e-17, 4.99894118103726e-18, 
    1.66937118339226e-18, 5.57221425225713e-19, 1.8551116584675e-19, 
    6.19134916917459e-20, 2.06148996410665e-20, 1.53199757115918e-12, 
    5.1242677380152e-13, 1.70368695413392e-13, 5.69216338939317e-14, 
    1.90179008833554e-14, 6.32609341883835e-15, 2.1131000981506e-15, 
    7.02605782635073e-16, 2.3376169835791e-16, 7.80526348754377e-17, 
    2.60175449584792e-17, 8.67691727803089e-18, 2.89230575934363e-18, 
    9.6410191978121e-19, -1.28743119870541e-10, -4.29614801763385e-11, 
    -1.42733865059546e-11, -4.77663825644817e-12, -1.59692344076522e-12, 
    -5.29952469280492e-13, -1.76650823093497e-13, -5.89307145839907e-14, 
    -1.96435715279969e-14, -6.54314648738314e-15, -2.17633814051189e-15, 
    -7.26388184560461e-16, -2.41658325991904e-16, -8.08354166475843e-17, 
    -3.34213514223801e-08, -1.11404504741267e-08, -3.70998020506295e-09, 
    -1.24016335466693e-09, -4.11986470363931e-10, -1.37679152085905e-10, 
    -4.58229849690495e-11, -1.52392954598903e-11, -5.086771725922e-12, 
    -1.69208728899472e-12, -5.65430410856619e-13, -1.88126474987611e-13, 
    -6.27438578589966e-14, -2.09146192863322e-14, -7.04099686149996e-06, 
    -2.34277773269333e-06, -7.82614399353772e-07, -2.60871466451257e-07, 
    -8.69993676951523e-08, -2.89997892317174e-08, -9.66237518943249e-09, 
    -3.21657050867084e-09, -1.07387865801294e-09, -3.5838167478498e-10, 
    -1.1929170941606e-10, -3.97639031386868e-11, -1.32968465909621e-11, 
    -4.41961853356742e-12, 0, 0, 0, 21056.5154533907, 45784.8132599718, 
    50320.4307246759, 50742.4797713472, 25517.5567691784, 8505.85331241304, 
    2835.28380385887, 945.094601286291, 315.03163936412, 105.010440852683, 
    35.0035858862512, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15708.2811797428, 
    26686.6324957569, 31409.9539344699, 16173.182964296, 5391.06159829487, 
    1797.02041072571, 599.006864594859, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -466.722375503667, -748.416068527254, -835.761859698124, 
    -425.432082316856, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    -1730.65348279217, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -341.18116282158, -647.517905189578, -859.484767096219, 
    -1060.73176963269, -1500.8468231943, -1795.33256947583, -1994.41440518138, 
    -1739.85011400715, -1547.96392182655, -1981.44779169851, 
    -2428.93851289593, -2448.42723141998, -2953.16739350923, 
    -2615.75033087765, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -18995.1206758564, -19050.3390499142, -19105.5574239719, 
    -19160.7757980296, -19215.9941720873, -19271.212546145, -19326.4309202028, 
    -19381.6492942605, -19436.8676683182, -19492.0860423759, 
    -19547.3044164336, -19602.5227904914, -19657.7411645491, 
    -19712.9595386068, 0, 0, 0, 37477.6785424152, 0, 0, 37477.6785424152, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 87201.9883875033, 87201.9883875033, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 8778.48174704963, 9116.82968716215, 9376.69728279068, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1232.01997926616, 
    749.716431256503, 855.612469495759, 683.200271101868, 413.768553343536, 
    297.785401408763, 406.027250728115, 335.445942409424, 275.653348241478, 
    258.757205909497, 253.982642121649, 111.617750036553, 172.55665296121, 
    229.624526424838, 0, -2770.21288354106, 0, 0, 0, -9640.3408347229, 
    0, 0, 0, -3989.10655229913, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6302.20972829056, -5711.37756626332, 0, 4135.49444251719, 
    6581.64623145537, 9567.25125213671, 10486.6421015327, 10539.4401857756, 
    10550.4577571942, 10640.8567346416, 11475.3377880798, 10845.1091778729, 
    11174.5620091962, 10224.6513107176, 10259.962431072, 10866.5875608733, 
    10049.5385795087, 712.161194316933, 988.507925490494, 1660.40280812631, 
    790.227581397336, -608.750293957247, -847.199777301192, -467.832778937881, 
    54.95878314737, -284.171055263922, 151.71920237511, -113.468246899084, 
    -308.192080042078, -94.844178901586, 249.387212102154, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-602L))
```

I want to make the stacked geom_area plot, but the following makes the plot with small blanks between layers in few places.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date, category1) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1)) + geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

[image]

I have tried to use `tidyr::complete` to make sure there's no missing combination of `category1` and `date` (and therefore silent missing values), but `df %>% complete(category1, date, fill = list(value = 0)) %>% count()` returns the same number as original `df`.

What is the cause of those small blanks and how can I deal with them?

Answer (score 3):

To get areas overlapping each other try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date, category1) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
    geom_area(position = 'dodge')
```

Change the position argument from `stack` to `dodge`.

## Changing the Position Argument:

[image]

As you're looking for a "stacked" plot, you may have to get rid of your negative values or switch to a barplot. See the following code and uncomment the lines separately:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date, category1) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # mutate(value=value+abs(min(value))) %>%        # raise scale to min 0
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
  geom_area(position = 'stack') #+
  # geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") #+
  # geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=7)
```

The problem with area plots occurs when ggplot tries to draw the areas down to negative values and then goes back up to positive ones. Unfortunately, this deforms your plot. So I suppose that you'll either have to get rid of your negative values or switch to a barplot.

This is what the modification of the code do to your plot:

## Raising the scale to min 0 (no negatives):

[image]

## The barplot version of the plot:

[image]

## The barplot version of the plot with adjusted width-argument:

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not what I need - `position_dodge` hides different layers behind each other, so the maximum value is maximum of all variables (172628 in this case). I need cumulative layer plot so maximum value is a maximum of sums of all variables (208249) - that makes a huge difference.

Comment: Ah, ok, I got your question wrong. Now I made some edits to my answer, but I suppose they aren't satisfying either.

Comment: You can remove the area between the bars in the bar plot to make it look more like an area plot, but in general area plots don't work very nicely with negative values, especially if certain layers change from positive to negative

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @MarijnStevering. I adjusted my answer and added one more plot. This might be the closest solution possible at the moment.